# fwrite on localhost with swedish characters php

Tags: php, localhost, fwrite

This code works on my webhost, but not on my localhost. How can I get it to work on my localhost (I use Windows)?

The filename bocomes "Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶.html".

```
<?php

$src = 'testing';

$file_name = 'åäö.html';

$fopen=fopen($file_name, 'w');
fwrite($fopen, $src);
fclose($fopen);

?>
```

Comment: It's working under my windows (7), PHP 5.4.3 ...

Comment: thanks for the info! Will try to upgrade PHP 5.4.3... :)

Answer (score 3):

MS Windows is well known for frequent problems with character encoding. In your case it looks like your "webhost" uses UTF-8 as encoding, whilst your local MS-Windows system uses an 8 Bit encoding. That might be some ISO-8859 encoding, but more likely it is the unfamous windows codepage 1251 or whatever that was which is nearly, but not really an ISO encoding. This appears likely, since you can see that the 3 utf characters are 'converted' to six characters inside your MS-Windows system. Typical for non-ASCII characters.

There are three options you have:

1. experiment with phps `default_charset` setting. You find it in the
   php.ini file your web servers php interpreter uses.
2. you switch your MS-Windows system to use an UTF-8 encoding internally as
   other systems do these days (which clearly makes sense). However
   this is not easy, especially to switch an existing system is
   probably not a good idea.
3. you have to convert all strings you
   exchange between the two worlds. Since autodetection of the encoding
   does not work reliable (in fact it can be proven that it cannot work
   reliable) you have to code specific conversions. PHP does offer such
   routines, but it is a pain to do that in the long run. And in this case, you transfer a php file, that would mean to manually convert all such strings (programming languages use only ASCII letters which are 'legal' chars in both encodings, but that is not the case for `string` values) to the other encoding.

BTW: you can play around a little with the encodings (to and from switching) by using a text editor that allows easy switching between encodings. That helps to understand what is going on. And a HexEditor is a very usefool tool to find out what is *really* stored inside a file :-)